# Is there a physical quantity related to all seven fundamental dimensions?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, si-units

For example, the dimensions of the universal gas constant come close: only luminous intensity and current are excluded.

$$ \mathsf{M} \mathsf{L}^2 \mathsf{T}^{-2} \mathsf{\Theta}^{-1} \mathsf{N}^{-1} $$

Is there any derived quantity that is expressed in all seven fundamental quantities?

$$ \mathsf{M}^a \mathsf{L}^b \mathsf{T}^c \mathsf{\Theta}^d \mathsf{I}^e \mathsf{N}^f \mathsf{J}^g $$

Comment: Brightness of a neon lamp as a function of pressure and current flowing through it?

Comment: Why would you want there to be one?

Comment: @JonCuster Aren't you missing temperature and moles?

Comment: @Javier - well, implicit in treating neon as an ideal gas...

Comment: @NDewolf Curiosity I guess. But we can always come up with more units. Where are the bits?